# javascript - dataTable pagination not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm setting dataTable on some dataTable, but pagination doesn't appear. Could you give me a hand and correct me? What I'm doing wrong?

```
  $(".support-table").dataTable({
"aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
"sDom": '<"support-table-header">',
"bDestroy" : true,
"bAutoWidth" : true,
"sScrollY" : "300",
"sScrollX" : "100%",
"bScrollCollapse" : true,
"bSort" : true,
"sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
"iDisplayLength" : 3,
"bLengthChange" : false
```

})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

```
sDom": '<"support-table-header">
```

and the pagination will (re)appear.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9aMDq/

`sDom` is used for styling the datatable, eg setting the order for elements (or "controls"). Here is an explanation from the inventor of jQuery DataTables himself : http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/37/the-sdom-parameter/p1 - sDom manual -> http://datatables.net/ref#sDom